# How to insert values in two different database tables simultaneously in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models classes in Django. I want to insert values in the models simultaneously using a CSV file.

Two models are User and User_Stats. User_stats has a foreign key from User. I want to insert some rows from the .csv file to User and some to User_stats. I am not sure how this will be done.

```
class User(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField('Full Name',max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField('Username',max_length=100,unique=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/%Y/%m/%d/',blank=True)
    email_id = models.EmailField('Email Id',blank=True)

class User_Statistics(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_posts = models.PositiveIntegerField('Total Posts')
    followers = models.PositiveIntegerField('Followers')
    following = models.PositiveIntegerField('Following')
def write_to_db(file):
    with open(str(file),encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
            csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            next(csvreader,None)
            for row in csvreader:
                _,created = User.objects.get_or_create(
                    full_name = row[0],
                    username = row[1],
                    email_id = row[2],
                    external_url = row[8],
                    brands_worked_with = 
                _,stats = User_Statistics.objects.get_or_create(
                    username =User.objects.get() )
```

What query/function should I write in User_Statistics so that both the tables are syncronized.

Comment: Please fix your syntax error and let us know what is not working, there is now way to update several tables at once with Querysets nor in SQL (unless you use transactions), just update them one after another

Comment: 1/ You states that "User_stats has a foreign key from User" but in your snippet it's declared as a FK on `Influencer`.  Please clarify this point - is it `User` or `Influencer` ???  2/ what do you mean by "so that both the tables are syncronized." ?

Comment: corrected syntax

Answer (score 1):

[`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) returns a tuple:

> Returns a tuple of (object, created), where object is the retrieved or
>   created object and created is a boolean specifying whether a new
>   object was created.

but you seem to ignore the returned object (by using `_`). Instead you might want to use the returned object and reference it in subsequent `User_Statistics` object creation. I.e.:

```
user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(...)
stats, created = User_Statistics.objects.get_or_create(
    username=user,
    ...other properties...
)
```